# How can I get consistent start times and durations when cutting a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I’m trying to slice up a ~20 minute video into several 1 minute chunks following [this approach](https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using--ffmpeg--to--cut--up--video), but getting remarkably strange results.

I first tried writing a loop with `-ss` after `-i`.

```
for m in $(seq 0 20); ffmpeg -i video.mov -ss $((60 * $m)) -t 60 -vcodec copy video.$m.1min.mov
```

I get a mess of different “start” times and video durations:

```
$ for f in *.1min.mov; do echo $f $(ffprobe $f 2>&1 | grep Duration); done
video.0.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3014 kb/s
video.1.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.012000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.2.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.012000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.3.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.011000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.4.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.010000, bitrate: 3001 kb/s
video.5.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.010000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.6.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.009000, bitrate: 3003 kb/s
video.7.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.009000, bitrate: 3006 kb/s
video.8.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.008000, bitrate: 2999 kb/s
video.9.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.007000, bitrate: 3003 kb/s
video.10.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.007000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.11.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.006000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.12.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.006000, bitrate: 3005 kb/s
video.13.1min.mov Duration: 00:00:50.57, start: 9.438000, bitrate: 3004 kb/s
video.14.1min.mov Duration: 00:00:50.57, start: 9.438000, bitrate: 3003 kb/s
video.15.1min.mov Duration: 00:00:50.57, start: 9.437000, bitrate: 3004 kb/s
video.16.1min.mov Duration: 00:00:50.57, start: 9.436000, bitrate: 2998 kb/s
video.17.1min.mov Duration: 00:00:50.57, start: 9.436000, bitrate: 3004 kb/s
video.18.1min.mov Duration: 00:00:50.57, start: 9.435000, bitrate: 3005 kb/s
video.19.1min.mov Duration: 00:00:50.57, start: 9.435000, bitrate: 3004 kb/s
video.20.1min.mov Duration: 00:00:50.57, start: 9.434000, bitrate: 3001 kb/s
```

If I instead move the `-ss` before the `-i`:

```
for m in $(seq 0 20); ffmpeg -ss $((60 * $m)) -i video.mov -vcodec copy -t 60 video.$m.1min.mov
```

then I get nice start times but variable lengths:

```
$ for f in *.1min.mov; do echo $f $(ffprobe $f 2>&1 | grep Duration); done
video.0.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3014 kb/s
video.1.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3003 kb/s
video.2.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.3.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.4.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3001 kb/s
video.5.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3001 kb/s
video.6.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.7.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3005 kb/s
video.8.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.9.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.10.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3007 kb/s
video.11.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.12.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3004 kb/s
video.13.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3003 kb/s
video.14.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3003 kb/s
video.15.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3005 kb/s
video.16.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3001 kb/s
video.17.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3004 kb/s
video.18.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3002 kb/s
video.19.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3006 kb/s
video.20.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3001 kb/s
```

What’s going on here? How can I get videos with even durations and sensible start times? Is something strange with my input video? (I'm unable to share it, sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was that ffmpeg was trying to be smart and not re-encode the video. This made it run quickly, but at the cost of the strange start and duration effects that I described in the question.

The solution was to re-encode the video:

```
for m in $(seq 0 20); ffmpeg -i video.mov -ss $((60 * $m)) -t 60 video.$m.1min.mov
```

This runs 100x slower, but it does at least produce videos with the starts and durations that I expect:

```
$ for f in *.1min.mov; do echo $f $(ffprobe $f 2>&1 | grep Duration); done
 video.0.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2108 kb/s
 video.1.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2519 kb/s
 video.2.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2318 kb/s
 video.3.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2573 kb/s
 video.4.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2104 kb/s
 video.5.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2292 kb/s
 video.6.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2219 kb/s
 video.7.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2381 kb/s
 video.8.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2184 kb/s
 video.9.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2726 kb/s
video.10.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2253 kb/s
video.11.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1872 kb/s
video.12.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2418 kb/s
video.13.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2624 kb/s
video.14.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2252 kb/s
video.15.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2426 kb/s
video.16.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2491 kb/s
video.17.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2276 kb/s
video.18.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2249 kb/s
video.19.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2071 kb/s
video.20.1min.mov Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2317 kb/s
```